# Add/Remove programs interface not accurate?

Tags: windows-7, appwiz.cpl

I installed dBpoweramp long time ago but it's only now that I noticed it's using 16GB of space (or as the Win7 Add/Remove programs interface says so).

I checked the installation folder of dBpoweramp and it only says 26MB.

I find it hard to believe that it actually uses 16GB. Is this a bug or is dBpoweramp actually using this space?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this MSDN blog, it can be [guessed and missed pretty badly:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx)

Comment: That it does. IMB there are many other locations for "data" that a installation takes up in space. Some install folder usually holds the original install/uninstall , the Appdata location can hold small or large quantites of data (depending) and now days there are even subsystems and support items that could be added VIA a programs instalation, that the program uses. Plus backups and last goods, and system restore, the layers of repetition are about 3X the program.  If I Trace an install I can discover most of what is going on easily. The before and after size of the DISK would be REALity